# How to connect ubuntu 16.04 via putty from outside IP

Tags: networking, putty

I'm trying to connect my ubuntu 16.04 computer which is at home via putty from my company.

I did connect it form LAN.

But what if I need to connect it from WAN?

How can I get it done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need a static IP address for your home system or [dynamic DNS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_DNS) entry.

In most companies outgoing traffic to `22` is blocked by the firewall. The easy way around that ist changeing the `ssh` port to `80` or `443`.

If your company invested in a next generation firewall, it can even detect ssh protocol an block that too. In that case use [OpenVPN](https://openvpn.net/) and hide the VPN [traffic behind https](https://snikt.net/blog/2016/12/01/openvpn-over-https/).

Keep in mind, that there might be a reason, why your company doesn't wont you to use ssh to your home machine!